# How to find the time axis of inverse Fourier transform in python?

Tags: python, fft

I have a pulse (experimental points) in the frequency domain. I used the code

```
func_t = ifft(ifftshift(func_w))
```

to transform it to the time domain. The problem I am facing now is how to get the corresponding time axis "t" so that I can plot:

```
plt.plot(t, func_t )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate it by using the sampling frequency 'Fs' so your time array would be

```
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0, n/Fs, 1/Fs)
```

where n is you number of points in your signal and Fs the sampling frequency

**Note**: Your sampling frequency is double your maximum frequency in your original signal if you follow the Nyquist sampling theorem

Comment: What does n represent here?

Comment: number of points, basically the length of your signals array

Comment: Of course it is useful, thank you.